Bottom alignment in multicolumns subsection
How can I always align text on top of the subsection to avoid situations, like those in the picture?

Code example
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\title{Test}
\date{May 2024}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \subsection{Sub1}
    \lipsum[3]
    \subsection{Sub2}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}


You can control it on a case-by-case basis by adding \vfill where you want the gaps to appear.


add \raggedcolumns
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\title{Test}
\date{May 2024}
\raggedcolumns
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \subsection{Sub1}
    \lipsum[3]
    \subsection{Sub2}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}

